# Incorrect syntax near '-'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, syntax

i am trying to run a query in another server and  need to specify it in the select statement but the server name has got an '-' in it, like server-name.
this is producing the error in the title.
How can i fix it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use square brackets `[]` around the servername:

```
select  * 
from    [server-name].[db-name].[schema-name].[table-name]
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across an SQL query on some website, which was supposed to be correct, but I was getting the same error. It appears, that some websites format text and swap the minus sign with some Office-like abomination.

Incorrect minus character: –
Correct one: -

Answer (score 0):

I also came across this error when I work with spring boot and MSSQL db. We may get this error, when we did not define the schema and the table name correctly.
I have included the below schema name with square brackets in the model class and I could overcome this issue.

```
@Table(name = "FIELDS_PARAM",schema = "[sample-schema]")
```